# LVM Check Disk for Bad Sectors with RAID Mirroring to Fix Them?

Tags: server, lvm, fsck, data-corruption

I'm working on creating a very reliable, high-volume storage server on Ubuntu.
Suppose you have a large 4 TB RAID1 set of 2 disks on LVM... At this size, I find it's more common to get a bad sector.

How can I manually scan the disks while they are live/mounted, and reallocate/fix any bad sectors? (Say, once every 3 months, to clean up any bad sectors.)

You might ask why the scan is necessary. My Reasoning: Because I want the system very reliable for infrequently-used data. Over time, disks degrade. So, it seems very possible that there could be a bad sector on disk #1, and then a failure on disk #2. That would result in corruption from bad sectors on disk #1, since there's no place to restore the data from. To help prevent this, I'd want scanning to clean up any bad sectors on a regular basis.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, running fsck on mounted partitions (I assume others as well) have a likely side effect of data corruption, which defeats the purpose.

Comment: Yup. That's why I'm asking the question. For large, multi-TB applications, I need to check the disks while they are live.

Comment: IMHO I'd consider data replication outside of the RAID, or use a different idea altogether, ie, CEPH.  +1 hoping you can find a solution